# Automapper entity framework foreign key is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to update the database using entity framework, I map my entities to viewmodels using automapper, and map it back the same way:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([FromJson] MyCVViewModel model)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    //find the cv
    CV cv = repository.FindCV(model.CVId);

    //auto mapper mapping
    Mapper.CreateMap<MyCVViewModel, CV>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<MyCompanyViewModel, Company>();
    cv = Mapper.Map<MyCVViewModel, CV>(model, cv);

    //edit
    repository.EditCV(cv);
}
```

When I map it back, the foreign key CVid inside company entity becomes 0, i think something was lost during the mapping process, how do you map the foreign key?

[image]

Here is my view model and entity:

View Model:

```
public class MyCVViewModel
{
    public int CVId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Title cannot exceed 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Statment cannot exceed 1000 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Statement")]
    public string Statement { get; set; }

    public bool Reference { get; set; }

    public List<MyCompanyViewModel> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class MyCompanyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Company Name cannot exceed 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Job Title cannot exceed 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Job Description cannot exceed 1000 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Job Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Entity:

```
public class CV
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CVId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Statement { get; set; }
    public bool Reference { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual CV CV { get; set; }
    public int CVId { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the error message when I try to update:

**The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.**

I see where the problem is, but don't know how to tell automapper to retain foreign key value

Comment: Where you able to solve this problem? I am facing similar and not only when I insert new ones, but also when I try to delete "child" entries.....
Regarding the new "child" for testing I was able to set the correct Id and it is working. But for deleting I still do not have a solution. Do you have?

Answer (score 2):

**`MyCompanyViewModel` class does not contain a definition of `CVId` property**, so by default Automapper does not know where he should take a value for injecting into `Company`'s `CVId` property. Just define it:

```
public class MyCompanyViewModel
{
    public int CVId { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

Then for each `CompanyViewModel`  add corresponding hidden input field into the view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Companies.Count; i++)
{

    // ...

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Companies[i].CVId)

    // ...

}
```

and you are good to go!

Comment: @EricWang, you will need to add hidden input field for every company in the list. Look for details in the answer. If it still does not help, please provide the code of the view.