# Automapper returning null for foreign keys with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

First of all, I know this question might be a dupplicate of [Automapper entity framework foreign key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955542/automapper-entity-framework-foreign-key-is-null), but none of the answers made it work for me and I'm facing some other weird issues and on top of that, I'm totally new to .NET Core, EF and Automapper :-).

The problem is that whenever I create **or** update a `Post`, which is linked to a `Category`, with Automapper, the category is saved in the Database, but it's not returned while it's supposed to and I really don't understand why.  It's actually returning null.  The GetPost method returns what I expect tho; this means that the FK are properly set.

This is the response I get, notice the `"Category": null,`

[image]

Here is my `Post` entity

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2500)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

My `Category` entity :

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

My Automapper configuration for a `Post` creation :

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>();
            config.CreateMap<Post, PostDto>();
            config.CreateMap<PostForCreationDto, Post>();
        });
```

And my `PostForCreationDto` :

```
public class PostForCreationDto
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(25)]
    [MaxLength(2500)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I try to create a post in my `PostController` :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost([FromBody] PostForCreationDto post)
    {

        if (post == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        var result = Mapper.Map<Post>(post);
        result.UserId = user.Id;
        _postRepository.CreatePost(result);

        if (!await _postRepository.SaveAsync())
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var createdPost = Mapper.Map<PostDto>(result);

        return Ok(createdPost);
    }
```

The `PostDto` contains an Id, Title, Content, and both Category and User DTO's, nothing special here.  The `_postRepository.CreatePost(result);` simply adds the Post to the Posts list of the DbContext (`_context.Posts.Add(post);`)

The `CategoryId` is in the payload I send so it should already be included..  But it doesn't seem to work.  I tried to hardcode it (`result.CategoryId = post.CategoryId;`) with no luck.  So I figured the only difference with the user is that I **load** it..  This makes no sense, but I just loaded the category and stocked it in a var (`var category = _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == post.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()`) without even applying it, and suddenly the `post.Category` is filled, don't ask me why. Anyway, this is not a solution, I just tried it and couldn't find an answer.

I guess there is a way to create a Post and return all the created fields, including FK's, so if anyone here could guide me through, it would be more than appreciated !

Comment: Could you share EF Command? And Automapper confg (if you have any)?

Comment: EF Command?  About the Automapper config, this is the basic config (I'll update my previous post)

Comment: In the `DBContext.Post` call, add include `Category`

Comment: I'm not making any API call but the one that adds a Post in the context : _context.Posts.Add(post);  .  I'm already doing the .Include(p => p.Category) in the "GetPost" method, but this is not really related to this subject and it works perfectly, the only problem comes from the Create/Update methods, neither of them are fetching data from the DB so I guess there is no way to Include anything

Comment: This an ORM, it works with objects.  Category should be filled before saving your post, as you did with your 'var category = _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == post.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()'

Comment: Ok, I get it.  So for any object linked by a foreign key (or not) to another object, I'll have to fetch it first before?  So what's the best practice here?  In this case, there is only 1 link to make but what if I have dozens of them?  It makes dozens of additional hits to the DB :s, and I believe sending the entire linked objects from the front-end is not a good practice, is it?

Answer (score 0):

So, as Hugo pointed out, the relation needs to be loaded in order to be included in the object EF sends.  This is something I have troubles to understand..  Right now, I'm loading the linked category right after I add the Post in my Posts context

```
_context.Posts.Add(post);
_context.Entry(post).Reference("Category").Load();
```

And I'm just Including it in my GetPost method :

```
public Post GetPost(string postId)
    {
        return _context.Posts
                       .Include(p => p.User)
                       .Include(p => p.Category)
                       .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == postId);
    }
```

But I'm pretty sure this is not the best practice as I'm hitting the DB to load the category.  Here this is just an exercice for testing purposes, I believe a good practice would be to return a NoContent response on creation/update as long as I don't have any other information to add to my response.  In this case, I could skip the "load linked entities" part.  This *could* become a problem tho, so right now I understand what the problem is, but this doesn't "solve" the problem, if there is anything to solve.